# Simple Email Service simplexml_load_string() error

Tags: php, xml, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails with Simple Email Service API.
So I have done this before, but now I get an error when trying to send something.

As feedback I use the browser errors from directAdmin and then I get this:

```
[Mon Sep 05 11:36:11 2016] [error] PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in <PATH>/ses/SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php on line 142, 
[Mon Sep 05 11:36:11 2016] [error] PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP 
[Mon Sep 05 11:36:11 2016] [error] PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in <PATH>/ses/SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php on line 142
[Mon Sep 05 11:36:11 2016] [error] PHP Warning: SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): Encountered an error: Array in <PATH>/ses/SimpleEmailService.php on line 380
```

Now when I look in the files at the line they give me, the only thing I found is this:

SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php on line 142

```
$this->response->body = simplexml_load_string($this->response->body);
```

And SimpleEmailService.php on line 380 ( is just generating the error )

```
trigger_error(sprintf("SimpleEmailService::%s(): Encountered an error: %s", $functionname, $error), E_USER_WARNING);
```

I've searched the internet for this error ( and maybe a solution ), but didn't found anything, maybe someone here could help me?

Regards.